# Sum numbers in equally long intervals

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python numpy array:

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
```

I want to sum the array in intervals of n elements. So if n is for example 3 the expected outcome would be:

```
>>> [6,15,24,33]
```

If n = 4 it would be:

```
>>> [10,26,42]
```

Is there an easy way to do this that I simply can't find?

Comment: .. And for `n=5`?

Comment: Special cases dont matter, let's assume the array can be divided by n without residual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) will do:

```
n = 3
a.reshape(-1, n).sum(1)
# array([ 6, 15, 24, 33])
```

Or for `n=4`:

```
n = 4
a.reshape(-1, n).sum(1)
# array([10, 26, 42])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])

n = 3

b = [np.sum(a[n*i:n*(i+1)]) for i in range(int(len(a)/n))]
print(b)
# Returns [6, 15, 24, 33]
```